# SUMX(VALUES( ), AVERAGE( )) returns unexpected value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I would like to use Measure to calculate **Summation of Average Value per Day** with the data below.

[image]

`Measure = SUMX(DISTINCT('Table'[Key]),AVERAGE('Table'[Val]))`

I expect the answer will be 100, however it returns 95.38 instead.
[image]

Is there any mistake i made in the DAX function?

Comment: Will you have same value for same day always?

Comment: @mkRabbani this is just dummy data to demonstrate the errors.

I expect the results from the DAX should be 10 + 20 + 30 + 40 = 100

Comment: Then give some other scenario as well in the sample data. Need to understand the logic why and how you need the output 100.

Comment: @mkRabbani  In my scenario, I have table of hourly data, but sometimes in a day there are varying numbers of data between 20-24 (data not always available for every hour).

I would like to know the Summation of Average Value per Day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below measure-

```
Measure = 

SUMX(
    GROUPBY(
        'Table',
        'Table'[key],
        "average",AVERAGEX(CURRENTGROUP(), [val])
    ),
    [average]
)
```